# Perl - downloading flash video

Tags: perl, video-capture

I trying to downloaded video from this [link](http://v9.lscache8.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams=id,expire,ip,ipbits%20,itag,ratebypass&fexp=913509&itag=43&ip=117.0.0.0&signature=9D4EEBD4E9DB5E05%206D56FC6FB7537BD797BA9E72.6227CBF7E77CD97FBA33BA555DAD7106804737DE&sver=3&ratebyp%20ass=yes&expire=1311955200&key=yt1&ipbits=8&id=173447de24d03eb9) using the Perl script. But the problem I unable to play the video after downloading. Here is my script

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
open(FILE, '>Test.flv');
binmode (FILE); 

    my $resp = $ua->get( $url
                    ) or die;               

    if ( $resp->is_success) 
    {
        print FILE $resp->content;
        close(FILE);
    }
    else
    {
        print "Failed\n";
    }
```

Please let me know whats wrong with the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not use old style open. Replacing the first two lines with «open my $fh, '<:raw', 'Test.flv'» would be greatly preferable.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this doesn't seem to work in firefox either, so I guess there's something wrong with the link. Your program looks OK to me, though using LWP::Simple would make thing a bit more trivial.

Comment: Link is getting truncated when I am trying to paste it. So here is the link http://pastebin.com/MV7qFJq2